# AVAudioEngine MIDI file play (Current progress + MIDI end callback) Swift

Tags: swift, midi, avaudioengine

Am playing MID using AVAudioEngine, AVAudioSequencer, AVAudioUnitSampler.
AVAudioUnitSampler loads Soundfont and AVAudioSequencer load MIDI file.
My initial configurations are

```
    engine = AVAudioEngine()
    
    sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()
    speedControl = AVAudioUnitVarispeed()
    pitchControl = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
    
    engine.attach(sampler)
    engine.attach(pitchControl)
    engine.attach(speedControl)
    
    engine.connect(sampler, to: speedControl, format: nil)
    engine.connect(speedControl, to: pitchControl, format: nil)
    engine.connect(pitchControl, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
```

Here is how my sequence loads MIDI file

```
    func setupSequencer() {
    
    self.sequencer = AVAudioSequencer(audioEngine: self.engine)
    
    
    let options = AVMusicSequenceLoadOptions()
    
    let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    
    let introurl = URL(string: songDetails!.intro!)
    
    let midiFileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(introurl!.lastPathComponent)
    
    do {
        try sequencer.load(from: midiFileURL, options: options)
        print("loaded \(midiFileURL)")
    } catch {
        print("something screwed up \(error)")
        return
    }
    
    sequencer.prepareToPlay()
    if sequencer.isPlaying == false{
        
    }
}
```

And here is how sampler load SoundFont

```
    func loadSF2PresetIntoSampler(_ preset: UInt8,bankURL:URL ) {
            
    do {
        try self.sampler.loadSoundBankInstrument(at: bankURL,
                                                 program: preset,
                                                 bankMSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB),
                                                 bankLSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultBankLSB))
    } catch {
        print("error loading sound bank instrument")
    }
}
```

And it's playing fine no issue with this. I have 2 other requirements, and am having problem in those

1. I have to play another MIDI file after first MID ends playing, for that i need to get the complete/finish MIDI file callback from either Engine or Sequence **OR** How can i load multiple MIDI files in Sequence? I have tried many ways but didn't help.
2. I need to show the progress of MIDI file play, like current time and total time. For this i have tried a method found in stack answers somewhere which is:

   ```
   var currentPositionInSeconds: TimeInterval {
   get {
       guard let offsetTime = offsetTime else { return 0 }
       guard let lastRenderTime = engine.outputNode.lastRenderTime else { return 0 }
       let frames = lastRenderTime.sampleTime - offsetTime.sampleTime
       return Double(frames) / offsetTime.sampleRate
   }
   ```

   }

Here *offsetTime* is

```
        offsetTime = engine.outputNode.lastRenderTime
```

And it always return nil.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see someone using my example code.

It's a missing feature. Please file a Radar. Nothing will happen without a Radar.
They do pay attention to them to schedule what to work on.

I fake it by getting the length of the sequence.

```
if let ft = sequencer.tracks.first {
    self.lengthInSeconds = ft.lengthInSeconds
} else {
    self.lengthInSeconds = 0
}
```

Then in my play function,

```
do {
   try sequencer.start()
   Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: self.lengthInSeconds, repeats: false) {
            [weak self] (t: Timer)  in
            guard let self = self else {return}

            t.invalidate() 
            self.logger.debug("sequencer finished")
            self.sequencer.stop()
   }
...
```

You can use a DispatchSourceTimer if you want more accuracy.

Comment: Don't use scheduledTimer for accuracy. The AVAudioEngine creates a thread pool of hardware threads for real time rendering. These hardware threads out rank scheduled timers in priority. Making Timer very inaccurate.